# Changing states of Keras stateful RNN model, layers and methods after creating an Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-estimator

What is the benefit of using `tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator` over a stand-alone keras model? For example, when we wish to serve the model in real time?

Let's take a this example. I have a Keras RNN, which is a `stateful` model. This means that when live data comes in for prediction, I need to do the following steps:

1. Reset the model state
2. Set the states from our last prediction for this user (if this is an old user)
3. Run `predict(x=x)` and also save the states outputed, for future predictions for this user.

In Keras, I do these steps using:

```
old_states = [state_h, state_c]
lstm_layer = model.get_layer('lstm')
lstm_layer.reset_states(states=old_states)
pred = model.predict(x=x)
new_states_to_save = [pred[1], pred[2]]
```

However, how does one do this procedure using an estimator? That is, on the:
`tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(model)` object?

How can I access individual layers and how can I access the `.reset_states()` method?

#### Model

```
num_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(None, no_of_features), name='num_input', batch_size=1)
lstm, state_h, state_c = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=320,
                                            return_sequences=True,
                                            return_state=True,
                                            stateful=True,
                                            name='lstm')(num_input)

dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(lstm_3)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(num_input, [dense, state_h, state_c])
```

**Edit** 
Estimator Layers[image]

Comment: If the estimator preserves the tensor names, you can set their values. Get the state tensors from the Keras layers and print their names. (It's recommended that you generate the entire Keras model with custom names in this case).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Few points about benefits of `tf.Estimator`

> What is the benefit of using tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator over a stand-alone keras model? For example, when we wish to serve the model in real time?

Well, I would rather add my two cents instead of copying documentation:

- > You can run Estimator-based models on a local host or on a distributed multi-server environment without changing your model. Furthermore, you can run Estimator-based models on CPUs, GPUs, or TPUs without recoding your model.

Well, `Keras` models can run on CPU and GPU "without recoding" as well. There is truth about distributed training, if you need it, it may be worthwhile to go with `tf.Estimator` hassle. Furthermore, as [Tensorflow 2.0 is coming](https://www.tensorflow.org/community/roadmap) I wouldn't count on this high-level API so much. Direction is rather clear, and **Tensorflow** will become more **Keras and PyTorch oriented** (with it's `tf.Eager` high-level API when it comes to the the second framework), `tf.Estimator` does not really fit the bill with it's function-oriented design.

- > Estimators simplify sharing implementations between model developers.

What can I say, they don't, just look into [SavedModel docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model). Using `tf.SavedModel`, exporting the model created via `tf.Estimator` is even more fun, just to give you a good look how 'easy' it is:

```
feature_spec = {'foo': tf.FixedLenFeature(...),
                'bar': tf.VarLenFeature(...)}

def serving_input_receiver_fn():
  """An input receiver that expects a serialized tf.Example."""
  serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.string,
                                         shape=[default_batch_size],
                                         name='input_example_tensor')
  receiver_tensors = {'examples': serialized_tf_example}
  features = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_spec)
  return tf.estimator.export.ServingInputReceiver(features, receiver_tensors)
```

Oh, and don't forget this documentation **will not** tell you how to load this model and use it afterwards (you can load into current session for example, provided you know the name of input and output nodes, so easy to share those models, love it).

- > You can develop a state of the art model with high-level intuitive code. In short, it is generally much easier to create models with Estimators than with the low-level TensorFlow APIs.

This point was covered, indeed tf.Estimator is more intuitive than low-level Tensorflow, but I doubt it's any success in the face of `tf.keras`. Still, passing three different modes, it's pointlessly functional-oriented design (+ all the fun with exporting), would get me saying it's a mid-level API (always good to have multiple APIs)

- > Estimators are themselves built on tf.keras.layers, which simplifies customization.

Well, that was `tf.layers` in 1.9 or 1.8, but that's being deprecated, so that's that when it comes to good practices with Tensorflow on the long run.

**All in all:** I'm not very much into serving (can't waste my time on the next unintuitive code with names like `tf.estimator.export.build_raw_serving_input_receiver_fn`), but you would be better off avoiding it if possible due to it's poor design.

Predictions could probably be done with Keras model as well, which would save you some time, but that's just my opinion.

## Accessing individual layers

First of all: **`tf.Estimator` is not like Keras models!**

> How can I access individual layers and how can I access the .reset_states() method?

Well, this is where the fun begins. You have to get your model within current session (e.g. loading exported `tf.Estimator`) and iterate over operations in the graph.

Schematically it looks something like this:

```
with tf.Session() as session:
    # Of course, your tag can be different
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(session, 
                               tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING, 
                               "/here/is/mymodel/exported/with/SavedModel")
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    # Here are all the layers of your tf.Estimator, sorted in the order they exist
    # At least they were two versions back
    operations = graph.get_operations()
    # https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/framework/get_variables this should work...
    variables = tf.contrib.get_variables()
```

What can you do with those operations? Those have quite readable names, maybe you could modify it that way (and reset rnn state). **Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45430933/tensorflow-rnn-lstm-reset-hidden-state) after obtaining your ops and vars**.

It's a long-shot though, as I have not seen such use cases unfortunately. I think that would be just about it when it comes to 'simplified customization'.

### Predictions

Well, a little easier (?), you just feed the graph inside session after loading your model, just like low-level Tensorflow:

```
output_names = "your_output_operation"
input_names = "your_input_operation"

with tf.Session() as session:

    # Of course, your tag can be different
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(session, 
                               tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING, 
                               "/here/is/mymodel/exported/with/SavedModel")
    x = obtain_your_example_as_numpy_array()
    results = session.run(output_names, feed_dict={input_names: x})
```

From what I recall, you can specify multiple output names, this direction may be a viable solution. To obtain input and output names, you can use [SavedModel CLI](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model) or print the operations and get the ones specifying input. Usually, those will be named like: `input_1:0` (for explanation of naming convention you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150834/how-does-tensorflow-name-tensors)) for input, and `predictions/Softmax:0` for outputs (if it's a multiclass classification). You outputs names will vary based on exported model specifications, exact layer etc.

### I hope this post helps you at least a little bit

PS. I think the best you can do is to leave `tf.Estimator` alone, according to my knowledge it's unusable and looks like a bunch of dirty hacks thrown together code-wise.

Comment: I have a clarification question about the way you have called the model using `session.run`. I understand why you used this format, but will it work with a stateful LSTM layer? I see that @GRS specified `stateful=True` in their LSTM parameters - will the saved_model persist the states of the LSTM in between different calls to session.run, or will it reset the states with every session.run call?

Comment: @Michaela I suppose you mean whether saved and loaded model will persist it's last memory state. You could check that as by default history is set to zeroes. If not you may want to create a separate question for clarity's sake

Comment: thank you, I did not know which parameters to look for in the LSTM to find the history, your comment helped. Also, after posting my earlier comment, I found [this post][https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710693/tensorflow-serving-stateful-lstm] which says that no, the history does not persist, which I am linking here in case anyone else has the same question.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I access individual layers and how can I access the .reset_states() method?

Estimators are themselves built on `tf.keras.layers`, which is how you should access the layers.

***The Estimator API provides a high-level API over low-level core Tensorflow API. The purpose is to hide the details of graphs and sessions from the end user.***

---

Why the `tf.estimator` exists?

- You can run Estimator-based models on a local host or on a distributed multi-server environment without changing your model. Furthermore, you can run Estimator-based models on CPUs, GPUs, or TPUs without recoding your model.
- Estimators simplify sharing implementations between model developers. You can develop a state of the art model with high-level intuitive code. In short, it is generally much easier to create models with Estimators than with the low-level TensorFlow APIs.
- Estimators build the graph for you.
- Estimators provide a safe distributed training loop that controls how and when to:

  - build the graph
  - initialize variables
  - load data
  - handle exceptions
  - create checkpoint files and recover from failures
  - save summaries for TensorBoard

---

Handy are [the Estimator class](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator) details.

Comment: How does one access individual layers in the estimator? `Estimator` object doesn't have `get_layer` method. E.g. `estimator.get_layer('layer_name')` doesn't work as with Keras. What I can get is a list of variable names, using 'estimator.get_variable_value('lstm_1/Variable_1')` (see screenshot) which I believe is the `h_state`. Could you explain how I would `reset_states()` of the estimator? I'm assuming since my mode was stateful, the estimator is also stateful.

Comment: From what I understood estimators model is Keras model. You need to create the estimator from Keras model as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295788/using-a-keras-model-inside-a-tf-estimator).